# Как разпарсить json и создать упрощенный объект для работы?

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите, как из указанного json получить объект в котором будет только то, что относиться `"sport": {"name": "Football"}` и его `"tournament": {"name": "Super League"}` для последующего вывода в `html` данных из него?

```js
window.onload = function (){
  const block = document.getElementById('football');


   async function getData(){

       let response = await fetch('https://api1.sptpub.com/api/v1/promofeed/brand/1699812984232222720/en');
       if (!response.ok) {
           const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
           throw new Error(message);
       }

       let result = await response.json();
       return result;
   }

    getData().then(result => {
        let data = JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t");

         console.log(data);
         let football = JSON.parse(data);

        // block.innerHTML =  data;


    });
   
};
```

```html
   <div id="football" class="bl_football"></div>
```

[image: коэффициенты]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это достаточно просто. Стоит посмотреть на данные и понять, что и откуда придется достать. Код выглядит следующим образом.

```
const sports = []; 
result.items.forEach(item => {
  if(item.length > 1){
    const s = item[1];
    if(s?.sport?.name === 'Football' && s?.tournament?.name === 'Super League'){
      sports.push(item)
    }
  }
})
```

В массиве sports получаем нужные нам объекты.

Comment: Спасибо, а можешь ещё подсказать, если необходимо в тот же массив положить и те элементы в которых market со следующих ячеек, как следует доработать код? * желательно что б маркеты относились к конкретному tournament.  В твоем примере они убираются из выборки что логично.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, не совсем понял, что требуется сделать

Comment: Полная задача - собрать в массив всё что относиться к футболу и к Super League.  Сейчас Ваш скрипт работает, почти идеально, осталось из result каким-то образом в этот массив sports забирать коэффициенте ставок (победа | проигрыш | ничья) как на изображении добавленном. Там по id но я не знаю можно ли в этом же цикле их собрать, или надо отдельный перебор писать?

Comment: Желательно отдельный добавить